# Delete geometries based on intersection with another layer

Tags: qgis, intersect, delete, flood

Working on QGIS, I have two layers

```
 1. buildings (polygons)
 2. flood area (polygons)
```

I want to get rid of the building located in flood plains. In other words, I need to find where those layers intersect and then delete buildings accordingly. I'm pretty new to GIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so be careful of using "and" in your problem statement (e.g., "find ... and ... delete"). As the current answer suggests, finding and deleting are different tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the processing tool "Extract by location" to extract the buildings that are disjoint from the flood plains:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]Use select by location tools on QGIS HERE Vector->Research tools->Select by Location

to know more :
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/fr/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=intersection